# Having Product Flavors with RoboBinding?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors, robobinding

I am trying to implement robobinding with product flavors but the custom code classes under the flavor's source directory never get executed.

Has anyone tried anything similar to this use-case? i.e. used some kind of element binders and then implemented product flavors?

On a certain demo project the structure I have:

```
-app/src/main/java/demo.app.pkg/MainActivity.java
-app/src/free/java/demo.app.pkg.free/MainActivity.java
```

`build.gradle` :

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId "demo.app.pkg.free"
        }
        paid {
            applicationId "demo.app.pkg.paid"
        }
    }
```

and when the `MainActivity.java` class is modified present under `free` flavor it does get packaged when the `free` flavor's debug/release is built. and is executed as well containing the custom code.

(On a side Note: some say that in-order to implement product flavors which has different versions of a single class one needs to have a src folder for `main` containing common code (but not the classes having same name present in the flavor's src folders) and other 2 src folders which have the class(es) having same name etc. which would essentially segregate the two flavors. 
 This wasn't the case with the sample project I tried above^ it worked flawlessly; even when I had the same named class under `main` src folder.)

Now, the issue lies when I try to implement similar kind of product flavors (as seen above) in a project already having robobinding implemented.
Structure goes like:

```
-app/src/main/java/demo.app.pkg/MainActivity.java
-app/src/main/java/demo.app.pkg/MainActivityPresentationalModel.java (class to be replaced by class present under 'free' flavor)
-app/src/main/java/demo.app.pkg/Pojo.java

-app/src/free/java/demo.app.pkg.free/MainActivityPresentationalModel.java
```

This thing doesn't work. Only the class `MainActivityPresentationalModel.java` under `main` gets executed.

Now, if anyone has used `view binders` especially robobinding or `SDK's binders` (still under beta) they must be aware of that we get access to a presentational model which is essentially logic where we have setter/getters to get/put values so that they get updated on the UI at runtime and hence my motive to have this class in a product flavor.

Any help is much appreciated.

Reference:

For the first sample project kindly have a look at '[Build-It-Bigger](https://github.com/horatiothomas/Build-It-Bigger)' project on gitHub.

Comment: @all those downvoting this question: do you have any reason for that? Then kindly post/comment as you're just acting like a troll if anything. A question on SO doesn't mean that everytime the `asker` has to post a whole bunch of code to prove something it could also be about "how-to" stuff at a theoretical/steps-to-follow level.

Comment: if you still have the problem, please post the issue and the link to the sample project into RoboBinding google group or github issue. We will have a look when available.

Comment: @Cheng surething! Thanks for the reply; I'll prepare a sample project and post a link in the coming days (sorry stuck with something :D)